# Store JsTree order back into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Hi I am using JsTree and got some of it working with my database. Such as deleting a node, renaming a node, etc.

I am having problems with saving the ROOT folders order back to the database. When I move the root folders, it doesnt save order. When I move the sub folders around, it saves order fine.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I think it's my javascript for the onmove.

here's a demo of what I am talking about.

http://healthsharing.com/jstree/demo.php

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Had to put a static root folder at the top to put everything else under and that made it work.